# How to delete a piece of string in PHP using regular expressions?

Tags: php, string

I'm new to PHP and today I found this problem. I have this string:

```
442_38489_ext/index.php
```

I want to delete a piece of the string: from end of it to first backslash (in this case /index.php), using only regular expressions in PHP.

Is there a way to do that? I tried this code but it does nothing:

```
preg_replace("/\/(.+?)$/", '', $something_not_important);
```

Do you know where my mistake is?

Comment: So, what did  not work? `$new_str = preg_replace("/\/(.+?)$/", '', $something_not_important);`. But a better option with a regex is `"~/[^/]*$~"`. What about `dirname($s)`?

Comment: No one is going to hate you :-) Welcome!

Comment: Wiktor, it just showed me nothing when i try to print variable that contains modified string. arkasha, thank you! :)

Comment: See a demo with `dirname` - https://ideone.com/MgECGw

Comment: Hey Wiktor, it worked! Thank you very much! <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [`dirname`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) for your concrete case, or use a regex like `'~/[^/]*$~'`:

```
$something_not_important = "/more_here/442_38489_ext/index.php";
$s2 = dirname($something_not_important);
echo $s2 . "\n";

$s3 = preg_replace("~/[^/]*$~", '', $something_not_important);
echo $s3;
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/MgECGw)

The `/[^/]*$` pattern matches `/`, then 0+ chars other than `/` up to the end of string (`$`).

Also, do not forget to assign the value to a variable, or it will not get updated.

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly fine for me...

```
<?php
$something_not_important = '442_38489_ext/index.php';
$something_changed = preg_replace("/\/(.+?)$/", '', $something_not_important);
var_dump($something_changed);
```

The output of above code is:

```
string(13) "442_38489_ext"
```

Maybe you did not assign the return value of the call to `preg_replace()`?

Comment: The problem with the current regex is that it will remove more than one `/` if there are more than 1 in the string

Comment: Well, the problem is already solved, but thank you for answering!